# Problems trying to install docker compose on Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to install docker compose in my machine with kubuntu 16.04, when I follow the guide in the docs for docker I get the next error in my terminal: `permission denied: /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`. In the same docs says that I would must run it with "sudo -i". However, when I run this and the terminal says me the same.

Looking for fix my problem I see that a [user in GitHub](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/652) (The user named aanand) says that I can download the docker compose file and copy in `/usr/local/bin` using `sudo cp`. I do it and for first time I achievement finish some. When I try see the version that was installed using `docker-compose --version` I get a python error that says me `ImportError: cannot import name split_command`. I see that in the line 3 and the line 9 of the docker-compose file in `/usr/bin` the version for docker-compose is 1.8.0, I change it for 1.13.0 that was the version that I tried install and when I try see the docker version newly I get another python error that says me `pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'docker-compose==1.13.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application`

The command that I used for download the docker-compose file was: `sudo -i curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.13.0/docker-compose-'uname -s'-'uname -m' > /home/<tree>/docker-compose`

*The characters ` were replaced for ' in the above line.*

[Here I left some screenshot of the response of the terminal when the version is in 1.8 and in 1.13 and the script in both cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hz4S.jpg)

The version in my machine for docker is: 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be

I'm new using docker, maybe it is very simple, but I've been trying for some time and I does not work.

I have hope that someone can help me to solve my error, and so we will be can help to others in the future

From now thanks Stackoverflow community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As root open the terminal and run the following command ;

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.13.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

[Got a “Permission denied” error?](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/)

> If so, your `/usr/local/bin` directory probably isn’t writable and you’ll need to install Compose as the superuser. Run `sudo -i`, then run the download and install commands below, then exit

Comment: Thank you. I was right, the solution was very simple. That solution is in Docker's documentation and I tried it a few times but it was wrong.

Completely an error of inexperience.

Really thank you very much.